# CakePHP calling a model function from a view

Tags: cakephp

I have this action in my controller (buy_it_packages_controller):

```
    function admin_index()
    {
        $this->paginate = array('contain' => array('User', 'Auction'), 'limit' => 10, 'order' => array('created' => 'desc'));
        $this->set('packages', $this->paginate());
    }
```

A link exists between buy it packages and user and auction.

The issue is I need to return a column from the Bid model for each row in the above paginate call. To do this for a specific auction I use the user id and auction id like so:

```
$bidCount = $this->Auction->Bid->find('all', array('contain' => '', 'conditions' => array('auction_id' => $id, 'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')), 'fields' => array('SUM(debit) as sumofbids'), 'group' => 'auction_id'));
```

How would I do that in my paginate query?

Buy it packages model has auction id column
Bid model has auction_id column
But no direct link exists between buy it packages model and bid model.

Answer (score 0):

```
function admin_index()
    {
        $this->paginate = array('contain' => array('User', 'Auction' => array('Bid'), 'limit' => 10, 'order' => array('created' => 'desc'));
        $this->set('packages', $this->paginate());
    }
```